# Rails and Apache mod_rewrite configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to point an old Index.php to the new root of my rails app

I tried this but still did not work

```
< VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.myapp.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/myapp/current/public
   RailsEnv dev

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ ^$
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type www.myapp.com/index.php it gives me the

- Bad Request!
- Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: why not handling 404 inside the rails app?

Comment: Do you mean writing my own handler?? Though about it... but why let the stack handle errors??

Comment: thats quite simple and it's very flexible.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in a directory container and fix your target:

```
<Directory "/var/www/apps/myapp/current/public">
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ /
</Directory>
```

This is assuming that your rails app is located at `http://www.myapp.com/`

Comment: hum... now I got the
Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @Marrento is `/` where your rails app is?

Comment: yep I want to redirect to the root. I tried to redirect to another existing path... something like /bar but I still get the same result

Comment: @Marrento if you want it to redirect, then you need a `[R]` at the end of the rule: `RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ / [R]`

Comment: Still no go. Same message... I feel we are so close.